# Is there a way to deal with numbers larger than \maxdimen?

Tags: tikz-pgf, maximum-values

i want to plot a polynomial approximation with tikz. Unfortunately when i use a polynomial approximation with order 5 tikz fails to calculate the result.
This is an example:

```
\draw[domain=1:10] plot (\x, {\x^5*(-0.0011577) + \x^4*(0.037895) + \x^3*(-0.48193) + \x^2*(2.9977) + \x^1*(-9.4071) + \x^0*(13.951)});
```

The result is an exception `Dimensions too large`. I know that this is because 10^5 exceeds `\maxdimen`. But this is no sizing problem, because after calculation this would be about 7. Is there any possibility to deal with numbers larger than `\maxdimen` somehow or is there any workaround? I'd really like to do this in tikz to avoid using pixel graphics (it looks way more beautiful when zooming in).

Comment: Have you considered using [tag:pgfplots]? It can deal with this automatically. You might want to look into the [`fpu` library](https://tikz.dev/library-fpu) (which PGFPlots uses) or using [gnuplot](https://tikz.dev/tikz-plots#sec-22.6) to calculate the values (or produce a list of coordinate outside of TeX and just [feed it to TikZ](https://tikz.dev/tikz-plots#sec-22.4)).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thank you very much! This is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

This is the result obtained with only `tikz` (and `math` library).  The issue of large multiplications is avoided by computing differently the polynomial.  See the function `dfiveP` in the code; it is the algorithmic way to evaluate a polynomial.  But even so the outcome is not really good because the values (during the computation) will be too small for `tikz`!  The figure below display the graph of `dfiveP`.

[image]

The first figure is obtained with `bdfiveP` which computes the same polynomial but after the change of variables x=10*t.  Now, as a polynomial in t, the coefficients will be bigger yielding more accurate results.

You can go even further with the domain since the function is decreasing...

**The code**

```
\documentclass[11pt, margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\begin{document}

\tikzmath{
  \a{0} = -0.0011577;
  \a{1} = 0.037895;
  \a{2} = -0.48193;
  \a{3} = 2.9977;
  \a{4} = -9.4071;
  \a{5} = 13.951;
  function dfiveP(\t) {
    real \s;
    \s = \a{0};
    int \i;
    for \i in {1, ..., 5}{
      \s = \s*\t +\a{\i};
    };
    return \s;
  };
  \b{0} = -115.77;
  \b{1} = 378.95;
  \b{2} = -481.93;
  \b{3} = 299.77;
  \b{4} = -94.071;
  \b{5} = 13.951;
  function bdfiveP(\t) {
    real \s;
    \s = \b{0};
    int \i;
    for \i in {1, ..., 5}{
      \s = \s*\t +\b{\i};
    };
    return \s;
  };
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=10]
  \draw[->] (-.1, 0) -- (1.1, 0) node[below right] {$x$};
  \draw[->] (0, -1) -- (0, 8) node[left] {$y$};
  \draw[blue!70!black, thick, domain=.1:1, samples=200] plot (\x, {bdfiveP(\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}
% \begin{tikzpicture}
%   \draw[gray!40, very thin] (-.5, -.5) grid (10.5, 7.5);
%   \draw[->] (-1, 0) -- (11, 0) node[above right] {$x$};
%   \draw[->] (0, -1) -- (0, 8) node[left] {$y$};
%   \draw[blue, thick, domain=1:10, samples=100] plot (\x, {dfiveP(\x)});
% \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```